# Is there some method to show attacks and defends and other statistics on board?

Tags: analysis

I want to teach children basic rules of openings and show them some critical point in formation with some kind of visualization.

How can I show attack, defends, weak points or other statistics on board?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Chessbase on a laptop to show games and positions. That would allow you to highlight critical squares and show possible moves with colourful arrows. [Here is a description](https://uscfsales.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/using-graphic-commentary-in-chessbase-11/) how to do this.

[image]